# Plot to the same GnuPlot screen in Parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, gnuplot, heatmap, gnu-parallel, gnuplot-iostream

I'm making a pyqt GUI that plots with Gnuplot. In some cases I need to plot a large amount of polygon objects (for a heatmap) and this process takes a lot of time. I was thinking about plotting in parallel, i.e half of the plot will be drawn by process 1 and the second half will be drawn by process 2 (each of the process creates the polygon and plots it in shared terminal).
1. Is it possible that two process can plot to the same terminal without overriding one another?
2. If not, any other suggestions for making the plot faster?

Note:
The reason I don't use pm3d and create the polygons/heatmap myself is due to the complexity of the mesh and to have a more adhoc plot.

Comment: No, there is no way to parallelize that. But maybe your way of plotting the mesh could be improved.